# A sound sometimes plays at login. Why, and how do I stop it?

Tags: sound, 20.04, login

I recently purchased a Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. I have had a great experience so far, but there is one really odd thing that I cannot figure out. Sometimes a sound plays at login, but sometimes it does not. I have not noticed a pattern, and sometimes it will not play for days at a time. I am stumped and would appreciate any advice on how to troubleshoot this. I am not sure what info about my system would be helpful, so please ask.

The one useful thing I have managed to find is the sound file itself:

```
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/alarm-clock-elapsed.oga
```

Since it is a type of alarm sound, I thought maybe it would be related to the default Calendar app (synced with Google), but I do not see any notifications from the calendar when the sound plays.

Using the suggestion from @waltinator, the package appears to be sound-theme-freedesktop.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/alarm-clock-elapsed.oga
sound-theme-freedesktop: /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/alarm-clock-elapsed.oga
$ dpkg -L sound-theme-freedesktop
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/sound-theme-freedesktop
/usr/share/doc/sound-theme-freedesktop/README
/usr/share/doc/sound-theme-freedesktop/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/sound-theme-freedesktop/copyright
/usr/share/sounds
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/index.theme
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/alarm-clock-elapsed.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-channel-front-center.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-channel-front-left.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-channel-front-right.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-channel-rear-center.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-channel-rear-left.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-channel-rear-right.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-channel-side-left.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-channel-side-right.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-test-signal.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-volume-change.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/bell.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/camera-shutter.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/device-added.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/device-removed.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/dialog-information.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/dialog-warning.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/message-new-instant.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/message.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/phone-incoming-call.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/phone-outgoing-busy.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/phone-outgoing-calling.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/service-login.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/service-logout.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/suspend-error.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/trash-empty.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/audio-channel-mono.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/dialog-error.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/network-connectivity-established.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/network-connectivity-lost.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/power-plug.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/power-unplug.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/screen-capture.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/window-attention.oga
/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/window-question.oga
```

Comment: Find the package that provides the file: `dpkg -S /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/alarm-clock-elapsed.oga`, then, do `dpkg  -L` on that package.

Comment: @waltinator, I've updated my post with the dpkg output. Do you see anything useful there?